# Best practice for handling multiple copies of the same input fields client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of input fields that are "stacked" on top of each other.

```
<!-- This controls which data set you're looking at -->
<select class="EditorInput" id="Selector" name="Selector">                        
   <option value="0">Link a new vendor</option>
   <option value="1">The ACME Company</option>
   <option value="2">Widgets Unlimited</option>
</select>

<!-- These values change based on the selection above -->
<input type="text" name="Price" />
<input type="text" name="SKU" />
<input type="text" name="Field3" />
<input type="text" name="Field4" />
<input type="text" name="Field5" />
<input type="text" name="Field6" />
<input type="text" name="Field7" />
<input type="text" name="Field8" />
```

Only one set shows at a time, but all set's values are kept in browser until submit. When you make a selection in the drop down, all of the input fields in the group change to show the user the values relevant to the selection. For example, choosing "The ACME Company" in the select field would make The ACME Company's price show in the price field, The ACME Company's SKU show in the SKU field, etc.

- All data and all changes are stored client side. When data is saved (via AJAX), all of the values for each set are saved to the server at the same time.
- Since submission is via AJAX, all the values don't necessarily have to be stored in input elements.

I can think of two main ways to do this:

**Method 1**

A single set of input elements, with data stored in a javascript object. On change of the select, the correct data is read out of the javascript variable and inserted into the fields. Any changes the user made to the first set are saved into the variable first. Choosing to add a new set saves the current values to a variable, then clears the values in the form.

**Method 2**

Have one whole set of input fields per option. Hide the non-active input sets. Changing the select shows/hides the right set. Adding a new set copies one of the existing sets, inserts the new input elements into the dom and clears the values of those new input elements.

**Method 3**

Use HTML 5 data to store multiple values, like:

```
<input type="text" name="Field8" value="$7.95" data-value-vendor-1="$6.99" data-value-vendor-2="$2.65" data-value-vendor-3="$12.24"/>
```

Then use javascript to switch the values into and out of "storage".

Which option make more sense? Or is there a better way? Also, with Method 1, where would the values for each set be stored? On the Select Option?

Comment: I would tend to opt for the one that has the quickest UI but that's just me.. In this case not making ajax calls would probably be quicker (although maybe you are loading more data upfront) but I'm not sure there is a best practice.

Comment: With either method, all of the data would be loaded up-front for all sets. Any additions/changes would stay with the browser until everything is submitted back all at once. I also had a third idea that I've added above, using HTML data attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a JSON-based data store and recycle the inputs, then submit the JSON store instead of form data. There are plenty of libraries (you're already using jQuery) to help with this on both the client and server end of things.